# Spring Boot with Angular 2 - place for assets(images)

Tags: spring, angular

I have a problem with mapping resources. I have multi-module project where first module if angular 2 which is server by Spring boot in second module. Everything is configured but the problem is connected with path to resources. 
[image]

On the left is compiled Spring module with added build Angular 2 app. In Angular module i have other localization for assets

[image]

but when angular build project, flatten the whole project and compiled strucutre is following
[image]

Comment: How do you configure the paths? which url do you use?

Comment: Resources are avaialbes as static resources so url are like localhost:8080/inline.bundle.js or localhost:8080/index.html. I did nothing with paths, the path which was set in angular project is the same when i build this angular project to  normal js and html files. Spring cannot deal with it but if i run angualr from node.js server it works.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't meaning routes, I meant how you access assets.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `<img src="../assets/yourimage.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">` as relative path.

And be aware of that image names must not be "yourimage_256.png". Spring does not like such kind of names and won't deliver it.

If you use spring boot security you also need to add

```
.antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
```

in your `WebSecurityConfig`